# Disable “parasitic” link behaviour at navigation menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pseudo-class

I've Worpress site with [JetOne](https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/) theme installed

When I click root menu element in the main navigation menu to open its items(links in that root element) click action for selected link (the root element) also triggered that's the matter. The problem is present on mobile view for that theme.
I already tried

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ct-main-navigation > .menu-item > a {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

But this trick just disables link for root elements of menu.
How to achive the goal right way?

There is another idea: recreate navigation using **wp_nav_menu_items** hook, but I don't want to break original design and don't know how to do that exactly.

**HTML**

```
<nav id="ct-main-nav__wrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<ul id="menu-menu" class="ct-main-navigation"><li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/">Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-333"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/private-jet-2/">Private Jet Charters</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-409"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/business-jets/">Business Jets Charters</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-410" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-410"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/helicopter-charters/">Helicopter Charters</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-408" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-408"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/air-taxi-services/">Air Taxi Services</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-78"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/">About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-299"><a href="http://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/#our-values">Our Values</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-300" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-300"><a href="http://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/#our-history">Our History</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-301"><a href="http://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/#our-fleet">Our Fleet</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-303" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-303"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/aircraft/">CESSNA 208 GC</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-304" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-304"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/aircraft/">DE HAVILLAND DHC-8-200</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-396" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-396"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/aircraft/">BOMBARDIER JET 200</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-397" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-397"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/aircraft/">EMBRAER 175</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-302"><a href="http://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/about-us/#our-team">Our Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/empty-legs/">Empty Legs</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul> </nav>
```

**Original CSS**

```
.ct-main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
.ct-main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'themify';
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
   transition: opacity 100ms ease-in; 
}

.ct-main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
.ct-main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a::before {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  display: inline-block; }
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .ct-main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
    .ct-main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a::before {
      font-size: 0.5rem;
      line-height: 2.25;
      margin-right: 0; 
      } }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .ct-main-navigation .menu-item .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
  .ct-main-navigation .page_item .page_item_has_children > a::before {
    content: '\e649';
    line-height: 2.2;
    } }

.ct-main-navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0; }
```

P.S. Another workaround for subject issue is make CSS as follows

**Modified CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ct-main-navigation .menu-item-has-children::before,
  .ct-main-navigation .page_item_has_children::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    content: '';
    font-family: 'themify';
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  }
  .ct-main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a::before,
  .ct-main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a::before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

How to make the fix universal not only for Android devices, but for iOS as well?

Current CSS fix brokes navigation menu markup on iPad(iOS) devices.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense to me -> `When I click root menu element in the main navigation menu to open it click action for selected link also triggered that's the matter.`

Comment: Can you show sample structure? Usually you have link for root item and then you create additional elements outside that link to open sub-menu

Comment: @Justinas done. 

I've added original markup and styling.

Comment: @MrT, That means root menu element also has a link on it.
So, the first role of the navigation menu root element is drop-down menu container.
The second - hyperlink to some page on site.

Comment: I think that is a design decision. At the moment the "root" link is taking whole space within `<li>` element, hence when you click on it you are redirected to the link location. One suggestion which comes to my mind is to move the icon from css into `<img />` or `<i />` element, make it bigger for touch devices and when it is tapped expand the submenu, otherwise go to the link location.

Comment: @MrT, Thanks! I guess you are right. 

Could you give me a favour and write down your idea as answer with an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is a minimal example on a possible solution:

```js
const icon = document.querySelector('.chevron-down');

/* for mobile devices you may also use "touchend" event */
icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const subMenu = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;

  subMenu.style.display = 'block'
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

i.chevron-down:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  font-family: themify;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 100ms ease-in;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://demo.curlythemes.com/private-jet/services/">Services</a>
    <i class="chevron-down"></i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Private etc.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is not a fully working solution and requires tweaking, however it should get you started.